# Excel Conditional Formula Range of Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells in a .csv file that are either populated with a "PASS" or "FAIL" regarding a result of a calibration performed. I am looking to create a formula in a separate cell that will display the overall status of the calibration procedure based on these numerous results. In order to reflect the overall result best, I was attempting to do an IF/AND function checking the various ranges of cells for the existence of "FAIL", otherwise "PASS" would be reported. Here is the following formula:

`=IF((AND(L20:L35="FAIL",L44:L59="FAIL",L68:L83="FAIL",L92:L107="FAIL",L116:L131="FAIL",L140:L155="FAIL",L164:L179="FAIL",L188:L203="FAIL",L212:L227="FAIL",L236:L251="FAIL")), "FAIL", "PASS")`

This formula does not currently work and I am unsure if my logic is flawed, the syntax is incorrect or if there is a more-suitable function for this use-case that I am unaware of. I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looks like if "FAIL" is anywhere in those ranges, it's a FAIL, else its a PASS

If that is the case, you can just count the FAILS, if the count is >0 then its a FAIL.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E7,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(G9:L15,"Fail")+COUNTIF(N16:T25,"FAIL")>0,"FAIL","PASS")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`=IF(COUNTIF(L20:L35,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L44:L59,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L68:L83,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L92:L107,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L116:L131,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L140:L155,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L164:L179,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L188:L203,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L212:L227,"FAIL")+COUNTIF(L236:L251,"FAIL")>0,"FAIL","PASS")`